# How do shields in the Star Wars universe allow weapons to be fired from the inside?

Tags: star-wars

During the many battles in the Star Wars universe droids, armies, and ships have shields up which are impenetrable to fire from aggressors, but are able to fire from the inside toward their aggressors.

How does this work in the Star Wars universe?

Comment: This is a bit terse. Can you be more specific about the incident that you're referring to?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Shielding in Star Wars: X-Wing vs new TIEs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197406/shielding-in-star-wars-x-wing-vs-new-ties)

Comment: What further clarity is needed above the edit above?

Comment: @Snow It seems fine enough to me, maybe a bit broad because different shields work differently and they work differently on different things. However, note only one of the close votes came after the edit, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

This video contains a fairly intelligent interpretation of this exact question:

Basically,

- **Deflector shields** repel physical projectiles
- **Ray shields** repel energy weapons

In the Star Trek universe, force fields work by way of pattern resonance, so energy weapons of a particular frequency are allowed through.

In the Star Wars universe, the usage is more ambiguous.  The best guess (as conjectured in the video above) is that the droid brain of the droid/ship that's firing the weapons temporarily takes down a shield (or portion thereof?) while an outgoing round is passing through.  This happens so quickly that there's little chance of an incoming round passing through at the same time.

As far as I can make out, there's no real canon explanation for how the "shooting from the inside out" works in the Star Wars universe.

Comment: FWIW [droidekas have the barrel outside the shield when they fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113008/58193).

Comment: Ray shields repel energy weapons [except when they don't](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99138/31936) (perhaps [deliberately](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/101990/31936)).

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 different types of shields in Star Wars: Ray Shields and Particle Shields. The former deflects bolts of plasma, the latter deflects solids (and maybe liquids and gasses). My guess is that the shields protecting gun bays are particle shields.